# Difference between int main(void) and int main()

Tags: c, integer

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    static int i = 5;
    if (--i){
        printf("%d ", i);
        main(10);
    }
}
```

I was reading article on geeksforgeek the difference between int main(void) and int main() but I am confused. How main function taking arguement?

Answer (score 1):

##### `int main(void) { }`

Here, you are telling your compiler *explicitly* that your `main()` function is not going to take any arguments. This prototype of `main()` function is standard.

```c
int my_func(void)
{
    return 100;
}

// the above function can be called as:
// 1. my_func(); --> good
// 2. my_func(21); --> error
// 3. my_func("STACKOVERFLOW"); --> error
```

##### `int main() { }`

Here, you are telling your compiler *implicitly* that your `main()` function is not going to take any arguments. But, there's a *plot twist*, in `C` leaving the function without any arguments (`type function() { }`) means you can put any value/variable in it while calling that function. This prototype should be avoided.

```c
int my_func()
{
    return 100;
}

// the above function can be called as:
// 1. my_func(); --> no error
// 2. my_func(21); --> no error
// 3. my_func("STACKOVERFLOW"); --> no error
```